# Monitors with ambient light sensors

Tags: multiple-monitors, performance, display, workspace, backlight

Looking for recommendations of any monitors (1920 x 1200) that dynamically adjust their brightness? I'm getting annoyed of having to alter my monitor settings several times a day!

Comment: Shopping recommendations are offtopic for Superuser.  (Unfortunate because I would like the same answer. :/)

Comment: You could probably edit the question to be less about shopping recommendations and more about what's the best way to set up a computer to adjust its video brightness relative to ambient light.

Comment: Just want to add that [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com) automatically adjust for the time of day and also can control Philips ambient lights..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a SONY monitor that does this, to answer your question. I purchased it in 2005; it's a fairly high-end monitor.

It does not require any software to be installed and is configurable entirely from the monitor. I use it with a KVM on various Linux Machines and all it cares about is ambient light in the room. The other answer requires Windows 7. A pure monitor solution would not.

I will decline to specify the model number (it's probably discontinued).

Answer (score 3):

Found a blurb [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Adjust-your-monitors-brightness-and-contrast) about Win7's handling of this feature.  Turns out the specific monitor is less important than what OS you're using & whether you have the required sensor.  Instead of a purchase recommendation, all you need is the terminology - look for monitors with an ALS - ambient light sensor.

> Adjusting brightness automatically
>   using adaptive brightness
>
> Adaptive brightness is a feature in
>   Windows that uses a light sensor to
>   automatically adjust the display
>   brightness to match the lighting
>   conditions in your computer's
>   surroundings. To use adaptive
>   brightness, you must have light
>   sensors installed and enabled on your
>   computer.
>
> To determine if your laptop or
>   computer monitor supports adaptive
>   brightness, look for the Enable
>   adaptive brightness setting in Power
>   Options (mentioned in the following
>   procedure) or check the information
>   that came with your computer.
>
> To turn adaptive brightness on or off
>   1.Open Power Options by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel,
>   clicking System and Security, and then
>   clicking Power Options.
>
> 2.Under any plan, click Change plan settings.
>
> 3.Click Change advanced power settings.
>
> 4.In the list, expand Display, and then expand Enable adaptive
>   brightness.
>
> 5.To turn adaptive brightness on or off when your computer is running on
>   battery power, click On battery, and
>   then, in the list, click On or Off.
>
> 6.To turn adaptive brightness on or off when your computer is plugged into
>   an outlet, click Plugged in, and then,
>   in the list, click On or Off.
>
> 7.Click Apply. Click OK.